# Inputs in the Mat Stepper are having the value of first Input

Tags: angular, angular-material

**Code for Mat Stepper**

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup" >
        <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Driver Details</ng-template>
            <mat-form-field class="form-field-full-width">
                <input [(ngModel)]="driverName" matInput placeholder="Name"  formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
            </mat-form-field><br>
            <mat-form-field class="form-field-full-width">
                <input [(ngModel)]="driverEmail" matInput placeholder="Email" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
            </mat-form-field><br>
            ...
        </form>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
        <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
            .....
        </form>
    </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

**This is how I set values into inputs**

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    var driverDetails;
    driverDetails = JSON.parse(params['driver']);
    this.driverName = driverDetails['name'];
    this.driverEmail = driverDetails['email'];
    ...
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
});
```

After reloading the page all the inputs have the value of **driverName**. How can I fix this??

Comment: are you using same ngmodel

Comment: Once you reload the page the component will be reloaded so you can try this.route.querparams function in ngOnInit()

Answer (score 0):

Found the Error. I have used same formControlName for evert input.